# vb.net, cannot call event directly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling

I have a piece of code:

```
innerchannel.Closing += Function(sender, e)
                        RaiseEvent Closing(sender, e)

                        End Function
```

There's an issue with

```
innerchannel.Closing
```

in which VisualStudio is telling me:

```
Public Event Closing(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.
```

How do I repair this to work accordingly?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? Are you attempting to listen to the `innerchannel` object's `Closing` event and have it handled by your local function `Closing`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want to add a handler to your Closing-event:

```
AddHandler innerchannel.Closing, AddressOf Closed
```

- [AddHandler Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [AddressOf Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you want to raise a custom event, for example in an `UserControl`:

```
Class Channel
    Inherits UserControl
    Public Event Closing(ch As Channel)

    ' this could be for example a button-click handler
    Protected Sub Closed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Closing(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't use `+=` in VB to add event handlers. You use [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx).

Your code is trying to call `Closing` as if it was a function and perform an addition to its result.

Answer (score 4):

firs you must to attach method to event handler like this:

```
AddHandler innerchannel.Closing, AddressOf Closed
```

and use [RaiseEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

note from msdn:

> If the event has not been declared within the module in which it is
>   raised, an error   occurs. The following fragment illustrates an event
>   declaration and a procedure in which the event is raised.